# Упаковать JavaFX + Spring Boot приложение в JAR файл

Tags: javafx, spring-boot

Написал приложение `JavaFX + Spring Boot` на `Java 17`..

В конфигурации указал

```
VM-options "--module-path="C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib"
--add-modules=javafx.fxml,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics"
```

Сам Jar файл пытаюсь делать так: `Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Add Jar -> From modules with dependencies`, но при двойном клике ничего не происходит, но при этом приложение запускается из `Intellij`. Подскажите пожалуйста как собрать `jar`-файл?